# PostgresSQL select

Tags: sql, postgresql

Im beginner in sql, so i need help...
I have tabe like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JLSm.png)

I need that my query bring back service_id: 5 and id:8, 2 rows(or its depends how many client_ids ill put in my where condition), with client_id, service_type_id, service_id, because service_start_date is max on those 2 clients. I have a full list of clients and i need to do it, thanks for the answers.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You want to select the rows with the maximum `service_start_date` for each unique `client_id`?

Comment: @StewartMacdonald yes, this is exactly what i want.

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables. Providing the expected output (again as formatted text) also helps to get answers.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thank you for the tips, first time here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used row_number() OVER( PARTITION BY client_id ORDER BY (service_start_date) desc)

it will give rownumber with client_id service_start_date descending

```
select 
   * 
from (select
        service_id,
        service_name,
        service_start_date,
        service_end_date,
        client_id,
        service_type_id,
        row_number() OVER( PARTITION BY client_id ORDER BY (service_start_date) desc) as ord 
      from servicetable 
      /* add where condition here*/
      order by service_id) as drt 
where ord=1
```

Comment: Thank you so much, im just started learning sql, so some tasks is extremely hard for me, thank you so much again!

Comment: The   `order by service_id`  is not needed in this statement.